# API OneSignal With CURL i get this Error (Please include a case-sensitive header of Authorization: Basic or Bearer token="" with a valid REST API key

Tags: php, api, curl, notifications, onesignal

i want to send a notification to (Segments) target like ["Active Users"] with parameter "included_segments" but When i call the API using CURL in PHP i get this Error : (Please include a case-sensitive header of Authorization: Basic or Bearer token="" with a valid REST API key.).

however the code is running well when i change target from parameter "included_segments" to "include_player_ids" .. but i want "included_segments" .. please HELP Me!.

[LINK to REST API Reference](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification)

- this is my Code :
  `

```
function Copts($titlEN,$titlAR,$contEN,$contAR,$icon,$img){

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
        "app_id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "included_segments": ["Active Users"],
        "contents": {"en": "'.$contEN.'"},
        "headings": {"en": "'.$titlEN.'"},
        "global_image": "'.$img.'",
        "large_icon": "'.$icon.'"
      }',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    )
));
 
return json_decode(curl_exec($curl),true);

}
```

`

Comment: What is working, and what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the **REST API KEYS** are not correct.
**USER AUTH KEY** instead of **REST API KEYS**
found it here :

> dashboard -> settings -> keys & ids

See documentation here :
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/accounts-and-keys

.

Comment: Glad you found that.  That would have been difficult for me to find.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you showed the values to: `($titlEN,$titlAR,$contEN,$contAR,$icon,$img)`

Add this to your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`

```
'Accept: application/json'
```

I looked at the example curl in the documentation
This is their example:

```
curl --request POST \
     --url https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications \
     --header 'Authorization: Basic YOUR_REST_API_KEY' \
     --header 'accept: application/json' \
     --header 'content-type: application/json' \
     --data '
{
     "app_id": "string",
     "included_segments": [
          "string"
     ],
     "external_id": "string",
     "contents": {
          "en": "English or Any Language Message",
          "es": "Spanish Message"
     },
     "name": "INTERNAL_CAMPAIGN_NAME",
     "send_after": "string",
     "delayed_option": "string",
     "delivery_time_of_day": "string",
     "throttle_rate_per_minute": 0
}'
```

This is how their curl translates to PHP using https://curlconverter.com/php/:
I think all the `\n` and extraneous spaces could be removed.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization' => 'Basic YOUR_REST_API_KEY',
    'accept' => 'application/json',
    'content-type' => 'application/json',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '\n{\n     "app_id": "string",\n     "included_segments": [\n          "string"\n     ],\n     "external_id": "string",\n     "contents": {\n          "en": "English or Any Language Message",\n          "es": "Spanish Message"\n     },\n     "name": "INTERNAL_CAMPAIGN_NAME",\n     "send_after": "string",\n     "delayed_option": "string",\n     "delivery_time_of_day": "string",\n     "throttle_rate_per_minute": 0\n}');
```

I do not recommend using

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Authorization' => 'Basic YOUR_REST_API_KEY',
        'accept' => 'application/json',
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
    ]);
```

Use this to make your HTTPHEADER:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Basic YOUR_REST_API_KEY';
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
```

I prefer the individual  `curl_setopt()`
rather than `curl_setopt_array()`
but I'm old, almost 70 years old.
and my profile photo is current.

Comment: I tried the modifications you suggested, but to no avail.
BUT i found the problem source was **REST API KEYS**. i was put **USER AUTH KEY** instead of **REST API KEYS**
i found it here :  _`dashboard -> settings -> keys & ids.`_
i want to thank you so much for your trying to help me and whatever was your age you will be always from gold.. **THANKS**.